# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/AlertDialog'. and '@android:style/DialogWindowTitle'

Tags: java, android

I changed the manifest's android:targetSdkVersion value and still have the same problem :

Is it problem with parent file or should I delete all this lines?

Answer (score 0):

Check your style.xml. You haven't declared alertbox and DialogWindowTitle there but you are mentioning it in Manifest. First Declare it. I am giving you an example to show you How to do it:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/button_background</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/editTextColor</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/alertPopupColor</item>
</style>
```

Simply declare like this in your style.xml for alertbox and DialogWindowTitle. Hope it works..

Comment: I try to solve it but i get an other error : Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: i'd like if you help me build this instruction